# Google App Engine stopping when no HTTP request

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a Google App stopping when no HTTP requests are sent. 
My App engine is listening for requests coming from an external API (DiscordJS)

This is my app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs8
env: standard
instance_class: B1
handlers:
  - url: '.*'
    script: index.js
basic_scaling:
 idle_timeout: 900s
 max_instances: 1
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This can be solved by using Stack drive to send a request every 60 seconds. This will keep the instants running 24/7

Answer (score 0):

Basic scaling does in fact turn down an instance if he has no requests coming in; yours is set to 900s idle timeout. If you want an instance that's always up and listening, you need manual scaling. Please check out the [scaling documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#instance_scaling) for details.